# multipart/form-data request using qunit

Tags: javascript, ajax, multipartform-data, qunit

I need to post picture on the server using ajax request in QUnit framework. When I do such request using `("Content-Type", "application/json")` I write this kind of request:

```
$.ajax({
    beforeSend: function(xhr){
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        xhr.setRequestHeader('authorization', userAuthorization);
    },
    url: address + "user/friend",
    type: "get",
    contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
```

What should I write for multipart/form-data request? How to point path to the picture?

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
var myForm = document.querySelector('form');
var formdata = new FormData(myForm);

$.ajax({
    url: '/myurl/',
    beforeSend: function(xhr){
        xhr.setRequestHeader('authorization', userAuthorization);
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: formdata,                         
    type: 'post'
}).always( function ( data ){
        // request done
  });
```

This code creates an FormData object out of your form and contains so a reference to the selected files.
See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData for more infomation about.

Then you can append the FormData object to your AJAX request.

Comment: When I do multipart/form-data request via Advanced REST client, it has such request headers: 
POST /user/avatar HTTP/1.1
HOST: 'url'
authorization:M3aW4GXbA....
content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary8AMsYZ7SnZnUgaBV
content-length: 410120
 
------WebKitFormBoundary8AMsYZ7SnZnUgaBV
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="picture"; filename="photo.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
I think my ajax request should look similar to this, but I don't know how to get boundary parameter and point path to the picture.

Comment: As I said in my post this (changing header & pointing to picture) is done using the FormData object and binding it to the AJAX request.

Comment: You can't get the path on the users filesystem.